# How to authenticate a user using ldap while ignoring NameNotFoundException?

Tags: java, spring, security, exception, spring-security

I am using Spring Security to create the login page for a web app. The users are registered in Active Directory.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception{
    authenticationManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource().url("ldap:MyLdap")
            .root("ou=MyOu,dc=MyDC,dc=net")
            .port(389)
            .managerDn("cn=MyCN,ou=MyOU,ou=MyOU2,dc=MyDC,dc=net").managerPassword("MyPass")
            .and()
            .userSearchBase("dc=MyDC,dc=net")
            .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})");
}
```

The user search filter is set to sAMAccountName because this is the unique identifier in the Active Directory of my company.

I am able to successfully retrieve the correct user from Active Directory but I get a `NameNotFoundException` thrown in the `LdapTemplate` class. The class cas an attribute IgnoreNameNotFoundException. If I set this attribute to true while debugging, the login happens correctly, otherwise I get the error caught and the login fails.

How can I set this attribute from the code? Or is it something I am doing wrong in my configuration?

EDIT:

Here is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
""
]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100213, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
""
]; remaining name ""
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:183) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:376) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1):

As per this [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/#ldaptemplate-configuration), the `ignore-name-not-found` attribute does the magic. If you can override this using an XML based configuration, that should do it. I am not able to find a suitable programmatic overriding for this yet, I will update if I find it.

Another way is to create your own bean which extends the LDAP Provider, but overriding this same attribute and injecting it. This should work, but you will need to know how the parent class is being used as it might break some functionality.

Comment: authenticationManagerBuilder.ldapAuthentication() creates a ldapTemplate, I can specify a custom contextSource but not a custom ldapTemplate itself... problem is I am trying to use spring boot, and avoid any xml

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to use a custom LdapTemplate, for it I had to define a custom AuthenticationProvider.

Here is the code in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception{
    LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapProvider=new LdapAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(ldapProvider);
}
```

And here is the code in AuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component
public class LdapAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate=ldapTemplate();
    Filter filter = new EqualsFilter("sAMAccountName", name);
    boolean authed = ldapTemplate.authenticate("", filter.encode(), password);
    //ldapTemplate.getContextSource().getContext(password, name);
    if(!authed){
        return null;
    }
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name,password,new ArrayList<>());
}

@Bean
public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(){
    LdapTemplate ldapTemplate=new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
    ldapTemplate.setIgnoreNameNotFoundException(true);
    return ldapTemplate;
}

@Bean 
LdapContextSource contextSource(){
    LdapContextSource contextSource=new LdapContextSource();
    contextSource.setUrl("");
    //all of the private configurations
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
    return contextSource;
}
```